# Skip multiple imports in react using babel-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am using babel with webpack in my react application. PFB sample react component structure

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ClassNames from 'classnames';
import Check from './Check';

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <Check {...myprops} />
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

**Check.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ClassNames from 'classnames';

class Check extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <div data-role='checkbox' onMouseDown={onMouseDown} className={className}>{children}</div>
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

PFB sample transformation data after done it by babel

```
var _react = __webpack_require__(3);
var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
var _classnames = __webpack_require__(327);
var _classnames2 = _interopRequireDefault(_classnames);
var _check = __webpack_require__(328);
var _check2 = _interopRequireDefault(_check);
var Checkbox = (function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(TextBox, _React$Component);
  ...
  ...
}
var _react = __webpack_require__(3);
var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
var _classnames = __webpack_require__(327);
var _classnames2 = _interopRequireDefault(_classnames);
var Check = (function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(TextBox, _React$Component);
  ...
  ...
}
```

I can see two variable declarations for each component 'react' and 'classnames'. I know, the same is used in both of the files. But, Is there anyway to avoid the repetition of the variable declaration after the transformation?

Comment: And you ask it because... ? Those variables are declared in different scopes.

Comment: bcz, Similarly I have many imports in different components. The hierarchy is too big for a single component. The problem is the file size after the babel run since the final version have too many lines of code.

Comment: So minify it. The size of the final bundle is compound of the libraries sources, not imports. You're trying to optimise something that does not even bring 1% of the total size.

Comment: Of-course. I am same with your point. But, just I'm checking here, is there any other way to collect all imports from the entry point file in webpack and to declare it as one.

Comment: "to collect all imports from the entry point file in webpack and to declare it as one" --- what for?

Comment: PBF the entry point of file in my webpack config. so, the "base" might/may be inherited multiple components with it.
entry: {
  testing: "./app/front/base"
}

Comment: Okay, so what's wrong with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98655/discussion-between-mr-black-and-zerkms).